# How to do "make <subdir> <target>"?

Tags: makefile

I would like a makefile where I can call:

```
'make' / 'make <subdir>' / 'make clean' / 'make <subdir> clean'
```

But I do not want it to attempt to resolve `clean` when called on a subdir!

Here's an example of my makefile:

```
SUBDIRS := a b c
all :  
    @echo building a b and c  
clean :  
    @echo cleaning a b and c
$(SUBDIRS) :  
    make - C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

All the calls work well except `make <subdir>` clean which calls `make -C <subdir> clean`, but then attempts to also resolve target `clean` separately. How can I get make to stop processing later targets?

To both answers:
thank you for your explanation. it is helpful to know what is and what is not meant to be done. i will not attempt this anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sigh*

Yes, you can do this, but it'll be an ugly hack and totally contrary to the way Make is designed to work.

The set of targets you pass to Make is *a set of targets*, not a structured command with syntax. Make is expected to build them all. If the makefile includes a recipe for the target `foo`, then Make should build the target `foo` a certain way, regardless of whether it is invoked as `Make foo` or `Make foo bar` or `Make bar foo`. What you are attempting to do breaks the accepted behavior of Make, so you should try a different approach.

If you still wanted to do it, you could do it like this:

```
SUBDIRS := a b c

.PHONY: clean
ifneq ($(filter $(SUBDIRS), $(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
$(SUBDIRS) :
        @echo make - C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)  

clean:
        @: # do nothing
else
all :
        @echo default

clean :
        @echo cleaning
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with Beta's statements on misusing make. Another way of achieving what you want, would be to introduce explicit targets for cleaning the subdirectories. This way, for instance, you can call `make clean_<subdir>`.

```
SUBDIRS := a b c
all:
    @echo building a b and c

clean:
    @echo cleaning a b and c

$(SUBDIRS):
    make - C $@

$(addprefix clean_, $(SUBDIRS)): clean_%:
    make -C $* clean
```